# Unable to run old versions of Firefox (<96.0) on Ubuntu 22.04 ("Channel error: cannot send/recv")

Tags: ubuntu, firefox

I need to use an older version of Firefox for some websites.

Any version before 96.0 or so (95.0, 87.0, 79.0, standalone, packaged) gives the error below, and all tabs start up crashed.

```
###!!! [Parent][MessageChannel] Error: (msgtype=0x21006E,name=PBrowser::Msg_UpdateDimensions) Channel error:
cannot send/recv
 
 
###!!! [Parent][MessageChannel] Error: (msgtype=0x210054,name=PBrowser::Msg_UpdateEffects) Channel error:
cannot send/recv
 
 
###!!! [Parent][MessageChannel] Error: (msgtype=0x210054,name=PBrowser::Msg_UpdateEffects) Channel error:
cannot send/recv
 
 
###!!! [Parent][MessageChannel] Error: (msgtype=0x390037,name=PContent::Msg_UpdateSharedData) Channel error:
cannot send/recv
 
[Parent 7565, Main Thread] WARNING: FileDescriptorSet destroyed with
unconsumed descriptors: file
/builds/worker/checkouts/gecko/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/file_descriptor_set_posix.cc,
line 19
 
###!!! [Parent][MessageChannel] Error: (msgtype=0x39005D,name=PContent::Msg_GMPsChanged) Channel error:
cannot send/recv
 
 
###!!! [Parent][MessageChannel] Error: (msgtype=0x390025,name=PContent::Msg_PreferenceUpdate) Channel error:
cannot send/recv
```

I have tried deleting `$HOME/.mozilla`, with no changes.

I also tried searching the error message, but I could not find a solution that seemed relevant.

Can anyone help?

Comment: What did you expect? System libraries sometimes have breaking changes. If you need to run an old version of Firefox, then create a VM with an older version of Ubuntu that was around when the older version was released.

Comment: If it is the case, then using a standalone library should be possible, if it was clear which and how

Comment: There is what should work and then there is what actually does. You'll need to deal with the latter like everyone else.

Comment: You do sound like you're pleased to help.

Comment: If there were something that could be done that wasn't hackey, I'd suggest it but this is the business of dealing with application requirements. You are free to attempt to use other libraries in order to attempt to get it to work but there's no guarantee that it will. Do you even need to use an older version of Firefox?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately - 1) A VOIP website requiring either Chrome (having some problems) or Firefox =< 87.0, 2) ad-supported streaming video sites, which don't seem to like the new ad-blocking protection in Firefox > 96.0. I thought it would be common for web developers to test older browser versions for compatibility, so I was surprised by errors. I don't know what they mean, or if they are only generic, but if it is a library problem, then I now have a few workarounds: 1) Use a virtual machine, as suggested above, thanks, 2). Use Firefox ESR (currently at 91.0, not old enough for the VOIP)

Comment: ...3) Install an old Flatpak (or snap) version of firefox, which seems to be working: (a) sudo apt-get install flatpak (b) flatpak install firefox [the new version must be installed and then downgraded] (c) flatpak remote-info --log flathub org.mozilla.firefox , then option 1 "system" (d) then choosing the oldest one on the list, sudo flatpak update --commit=72e9f7bb3d3df645d9b78f6f7fdf8f292c11eb654a86e1ac17d2db0528b45dfd org.mozilla.firefox   (e) Finally, run with: flatpak run org.mozilla.firefox

Answer (score 2):

I also have encountered with this problem with Firefox 88. This is caused by new version of Glibc.

---

### Important

From discussion in bugreport https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=1020894
: in glibc 2.34 changed API. Changed API have supported in Firefox 91 and higher.

> To continue using Firefox 88, you might want to disable the sandbox
> filter by setting the MOZ_DISABLE_CONTENT_SANDBOX environment variable
> to 1 (e.g. export MOZ_DISABLE_CONTENT_SANDBOX=1) before launching
> Firefox, but please be aware of the security implications.

Comment: Err ?? Don't tell me you downgraded the glibc for the sole sake of Firefox happyness ? What would be your next advice ? Downgrading gcc ? Not to say that… for having built firefox 91 esr on my system, it perfectly works with glibc-2.35 current stable.

Comment: Yes, downgrade. But this is only my experience, not advice.

Comment: My opinion is that it should not even be a suggestion because **downgrading glibc is the most certain way to break your toolchain,** with the consequences you might imagine. Many distributions don't even allow you to proceed via their package manager : *"Sanity check to keep you from breaking your system: Downgrading glibc is not supported and a sure way to destruction"* (this one from gentoo's portage).

Comment: I agree with you, downgrading is not good way. Therefore, I created bugreport https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=1020894

Comment: From discussion in bugreport:
In glibc 2.34 changed API. Changed API have supported in Firefox 91 and higher.
And:
"To continue using Firefox 88, you might want to disable the sandbox
filter by setting the MOZ_DISABLE_CONTENT_SANDBOX environment variable
to 1 (e.g. export MOZ_DISABLE_CONTENT_SANDBOX=1) before launching
Firefox, but please be aware of the security implications."

Comment: Very important piece of information you managed to find. Sincere congrats ! PLEASE do edit your answer accordingly then granted ! it will be a pleasure for me to change my downvote into an upvote. :-)